# What is the actual value of "line.separator"?

Tags: java, string, char

I always think that `line.separator` do the same things as `\n`, and **yes it is**. but I noticed that both values are actually not the same(perhaps not even close?) when I test this code:

```
String str1 = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String str2 = "\n";

System.out.println(str1.equals(str2)); // output:false (as expected)
```

Then I checked the length of both:

```
System.out.println(str1.length());     //output: 2
System.out.println(str2.length());     //output: 1
```

wondering why `str1.length()` is `2`, I tried this:

```
System.out.println("**"+str1.charAt(0)+"**");
```

output:

```
**

System.out.println("##"+str1.charAt(1)+"##");
```

output:

```
##
##
```

So I noticed that the actual *newline character* in `line.separator` is the second character. Then what is the value in first index, as when it supposed to print `****` (atleast), its print `**` instead?

Comment: It's different on different OS's. Windows is `\r\n`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on your OS.

For windows, the actual value of `line.separator` is `\r\n`

From your code `System.out.println(str1.length());     //output: 2`, I believe you are on Windows's OS (*Other OS will give output: 1*)

It explain why got this output:

```
System.out.println("**"+str1.charAt(0)+"**");
```

output:

```
**
```

`\r` is a carriage return, after you print `**` the pointer is returned back to the initial point, and print the second `**`, which rewrite the first `**`. Finally, you got only `**` as output

And for the second one:

```
System.out.println("##"+str1.charAt(1)+"##");
```

output:

```
##
##
```

you got such output because `str1.charAt(1)` is actually `\n`

Comment: It depends on your operating system. `\r\n` is Windows specific.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen from the question, `str1.length()) = 2`. then I'm pretty sure it is Windows OS :D

Answer (score 6):

It's depends on the platform/OS, in Linux it's `\n`, in Windows, it's `\r\n`

```
Windows: '\r\n'
Mac (OS 9-): '\r'
Mac (OS 10+): '\n'
Unix/Linux: '\n'
```

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, it's "\r\n", on *NIX, it's "\n", on pre-OSX Mac it is "\r".  You retrieve it from the `System` object because it's OS-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Line Feed – LF – \n – 0x0a – 10 (decimal)

Carriage Return – CR – \r – 0x0D – 13 (decimal)

Now that we have understood that we have two different options to get new line, the question that arises is – why is it so?

The reason is simple. Different operating systems have a different way of understanding new line. Mac only understands ‘\r’ as new line, while Unix and Linux understand ‘\n’ as new line character. Our favorite OS windows needs both the characters together to interpret as new line, which is ‘\r\n’. This is the reason why a file created in one OS does not open properly in another OS and makes it messy.